# Codeigniter shorten urls

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to create such urls in codeigniter?
http://site.com/shorturl/

Where shorturl isn't a physical controller file, but a variable.

I expect the algorythm for parsing url query to be like this:
1) Search for physical controller file. If exists, do standard codeigniter routine. If not
2) Try to load special controller file, where "shorturl" is a variable. Do further stuff inside that controller.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can easily do it with router. Just keep the sequence in order. See the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer seems quite good, but thought I'd share what I'd though of.

If you set your `404_override` to point to a controller you have set up as follows:

```
$route['404_override'] = 'welcome/short';
```

Any URL that doesn't exist (any short URL for example) would get sent there, where you could do the following to check the value:

```
public function short() {

    $shortCode = $this->uri->segment(1);

}
```

That would give you the value you need to check. If all is well, do the redirect, if the code doesn't exist, you can then use the `show_404` method to actually show the 404 page.

Comment: I like this simple solution most of all. Thanks!